# replace string to asterisk bash

Tags: regex, bash, sed, rhel

I am trying to get from user a path as an input.
The user will enter a specific path for specific application:

```
script.sh /var/log/dbhome_1/md5
```

I've wanted to convert the number of directory (in that case - 1) to * (asterisk). later on, the script will do some logic on this path.

When i'm trying sed on the input, i'm stuck with the number -

```
echo "/var/log/dbhome_1/md5" | sed "s/dbhome_*/dbhome_\*/g"
```

and the input will be -

```
/var/log/dbhome_*1/md5
```

I know that i have some problems with the asterisk wildcard and as a char...
maybe regex will help here?

Answer (score 3):

Code for GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed "s#1/#\*/#"
```

.

```
$echo "/var/log/dbhome_1/md5" | sed "s#1/#\*/#"
"/var/log/dbhome_*/md5"
```

---

Or more general:

```
sed "s#[0-9]\+/#\*/#"
```

.

```
$echo "/var/log/dbhome_1234567890/md5" | sed "s#[0-9]\+/#\*/#"
"/var/log/dbhome_*/md5"
```

Answer (score 2):

use this instead:

```
echo "/var/log/dbhome_1/md5" | sed "s/dbhome_[0-9]\+/dbhome_\*/g"
```

`[0-9]` is a character class that contains all digits

Thus `[0-9]\+` matches one or more digits

Comment: [0-9] will cover all numbers ? I don't know if the number is 1 or even 13294 .. Thank you!

Comment: @user2160077: Try <°))))))>!

Answer (score 0):

If your script is in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) (which I assume when I see the tag, but I also doubt it when I see its name `script.sh` which seems to have the wrong extension for a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script), you might as well use pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) stuff: `/var/log/dbhome_1/md5` will very likely be in positional parameter `$1`, and what you want will be achieved by:

```
echo "${1//dbhome_+([[:digit:]])/dbhome_*}"
```

If this seems to fail, it's probably because your `extglob` shell optional behavior is turned off. In this case, just turn it on with

```
shopt -s extglob
```

Demo:

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ a=/var/log/dbhome_1234567/md5
$ echo "${a//dbhome_+([[:digit:]])/dbhome_*}"
/var/log/dbhome_*/md5
$
```

Done!